# gradient tranisition on click

Tags: javascript, css, gradient, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

I am looking to transition gradients as part of a dark mode on my website. So on click and not on hover. Also my gradients are a little more complex than two-color linear gradients that previous posts seem to cover but I will figure out new ones if something can be done to transition them on click.

```
radial-gradient( circle farthest-corner at -4% -12.9%,  rgba(74,98,110,1) 0.3%, rgba(30,33,48,1) 90.2% )
        
linear-gradient( 68.4deg,  rgba(248,182,204,1) 0.5%, rgba(192,198,230,1) 49%, rgba(225,246,240,1) 99.8% )
```

I tried basically every CSS trick from every post here but they all seem to rely on :hover

Comment: You will need to have a little bit of JS onclick. Please include a runnable snippet to make it easier to help you - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and could you clarify - you want to transition between the radial gradient and the linear gradient backgrounds. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

background-image has animation type discrete, which means it will jump from the initial value to the new value (though some browsers will animate gradually between CSS keyframes, but not all).

One way round this is to gradually fade out the first background and gradually fade in the second background.

This snippet does this by adding before and after pseudo elements to the body element.

When a button is clicked it sets opacity of the before to 0 and the opacity of the after to 1. The effect is rendered gradual by the addition of a transition property - opacity is an animatable property.

```html
<style>
  body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  body::before,
  body::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: opacity 5s linear;
  }
  
  body::before {
    background-image: radial-gradient( circle farthest-corner at -4% -12.9%, rgba(74, 98, 110, 1) 0.3%, rgba(30, 33, 48, 1) 90.2%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  body.change::before {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  body::after {
    opacity: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient( 68.4deg, rgba(248, 182, 204, 1) 0.5%, rgba(192, 198, 230, 1) 49%, rgba(225, 246, 240, 1) 99.8%);
  }
  
  body.change::after {
    opacity: 1;
  }
</style>

<body><button onclick="document.body.classList.add('change');">click me</button></body>
```

Comment: So that seems to be what I am looking for except the button only goes one way. Is there a way to make it transition back to the original gradient?

Comment: Have you tried reversing the animations? Have a good look at the code here and make sure you understand it.

Comment: Ahh with React state that's a no brainer

Comment: well not with state, body tag not being part of react directly, but it's working

Comment: Not sure where React comes into it, the question didn’t hint at that being the context.

Comment: I didn't notice initially but it doesnt cover the full body, it's cutting off after part of my page https://i.imgur.com/ikuFd4V.png

Comment: This doesn’t happen with my code so I suspect there’s something else in your context making this happen. What element have you got the background set on?

Comment: The background is on the body element, I suspect it's something to do with it being a React project.

Comment: Perhaps have a look through your browser's devtools inspect facility to see who/where is setting the height of the body element.

Comment: It seems that changing from `position: absolute` to `position: fixed` resolved the issue.